# Compress files with same name in powershell

Tags: powershell, zip, file-extension

I have a folder with more than 1000 file extensions.

This is a sample of my files.

- AFG.cpg
- AFG.dbf
- AFG.prj
- AFG.sbn
- AFG.sbx
- AFG. shp
- AFG.shx
- AFG.cpg
- AGO.dbf
- AGO.prj
- AGO.sbn
- AGO.sbx
- AGO. shp
- AGO.shx

I want to zip them according to the first 3 letters. For the sample, I am looking to get two zip files, one for AFG.zip, and AGO.zip.

I was able to compress one file using the following, but the resulting folder returns with the directory name "countries" instead of the file name:

```
$compress = @{
LiteralPath= "C:\Countries"
CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
DestinationPath = "C:\Countries\Draft.Zip"
}
Compress-Archive @compress
```

I also tried the following to group the files and compress them:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Countries | 
    Group-Object -Property { $_.Name.Substring(0, 3) } |
    % { Compress-Archive -Path $_.Group -DestinationPath "$($_.Name).zip" }
```

But I am getting the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Compress-Archive : The path 'AFG.cpg' either does not exist or is not a valid file system
path.
[ERROR] At line:3 char:9
+     % { Compress-Archive -Path $_.Group -DestinationPath "$($_.Name). ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (AFG.cpg:String) [Compress-Archive], InvalidO
   perationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArchiveCmdletPathNotFound,Compress-Archive
```

I believe the error has to do with the third line: > { Compress-Archive -Path $*.Group -DestinationPath "$($*.Name).zip" }, but not sure how to fix it. I also tried some other code to do this, as this is kind of a popular question but they don't seem to work. I just started to use powershell for this, thank you for any help.

I am using powershell x86.

Comment: Try`Compress-Archive -Path $_.Group.FullName`. Currently you give the compress comand a list of objects. But by definition of the parameter -Path it only takes a string or an array of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to zip each of my files thanks to @guiwhatsthat comment. This is the fixed code:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Folder | 
    Group-Object -Property { $_.Name.Substring(0, 3) } |
    % { Compress-Archive -Path $_.Group.FullName -DestinationPath "$($_.Name).zip" }
```